# Setting up Postfix for outgoing application email only

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix

It turns out that I [cannot](https://serverfault.com/questions/254782/logwatch-without-mta-postfix) use Nullmailer so that Logwatch and other services, like Wordpress, can send email. So I have just now set up Postfix by [issuing two first two commands here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix). I now wonder if there is anything else I need to do post-installation to make sure that Postfix is working properly and is secure.

I've tested to send email through Wordpress and it works.

Note: Postfix will only be used to send outgoing email by the system. User email is managed using Google apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the default install then relaying should be disabled by default.
It would be easier to check if you could post your /etc/postfix/main.cf.

Answer (score 1):

The default Ubuntu install should be fine, and secure. Goto a relay tester like [Open Relay Test](http://www.spamhelp.org/shopenrelay/) to check no-one can mail through you to spam.

Keeping Postfix up to date with `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade" every now and again should be pretty future proof.